# Running web socket server on opera 12

Tags: html, node.js, websocket, opera

I followed the instructions from here to install web socket node.js server on my WXP

I have a client and server written as follows:  http://cjihrig.com/blog/creating-your-own-websocket-echo-client/  (ws_server.js)

Please let me know how can I make the web socket connection work...?
When I run the client, Alert displaye are as follows:
1. "Web sockets are supported"
2. "On Close : event / data :Undefined".

So how do i make nodejs work on opera?? It is working fine on google chrome??

I have enabled web sockets in opera config

Thanks
Sneha

Answer (score 2):

The current release version of Opera 12 is

```
Opera/9.80 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7.4; U; fr) Presto/2.10.289 Version/12.00
```

as you can see in the user agent string: **Presto/2.10.289**. The last version of WebSocket Protocol has [been implemented](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto2.11/index.dml#m211-337) in the CORE engine of Opera.

> WebSocket API Update WebSocket implementation to RFC 6455
>   (**Presto/2.11.337**)
>
> - See: The WebSocket API
> - See: RFC 6455 - The WebSocket Protocol

but as you can see in **Presto/2.11.337** which is not yet available in Opera 12. It will be available in a future release.

Answer (score 0):

According to [protocol support section](https://github.com/einaros/ws#protocol-support) Opera uses very old **Hixie draft 76**. Maybe when you use [ws](http://einaros.github.com/ws/) you will have more luck. Furthermore I think you need a project which supports multiple transports(websockets/longpolling etc) like for example [faye.js](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) or [socket.io](http://socket.io)